# CSS3 transition: how can I trigger this event with a link? JSFiddle demo inside

Tags: css, transition

**http://jsfiddle.net/9WsnA/**

Currently, the transition is triggered by hovering over the container div just to show you what I am trying to accomplish. I'd like to create link1 and link2 above the container div to trigger these transitions where link1 would obviously display the first div and link2 would slide it over to the second div.

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    }

/* elements */

#serpcontainer {
    margin:0;
    width:200%;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:all .2s ease-out;
    }
#serpcontainer:hover {
    margin:0 0 0 -100%;
    }
#serp1 {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    background:pink;
    }
#serp2 {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    background:cyan;
    }

/* animations */

@keyframes slide {
    from {
        margin:0 0 0 100%;
        }
    to {
        margin:0;
        }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="serpcontainer">
    <div id="serp1">
        1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
    </div>
    <div id="serp2">
        22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this code   http://jsfiddle.net/9WsnA/6/

```
    $('.linkOne').click(function(){
        $('#serpcontainer').addClass('linkOneContent');
        $('#serpcontainer').removeClass('linkTwoContent');
    });
    $('.linkTwo').click(function(){
        $('#serpcontainer').addClass('linkTwoContent');
        $('#serpcontainer').removeClass('linkOneContent');
    });
```

Updated css some lines

Comment: Assume the second div had a lot of content in it which would make the vertical scroll bar show even when you were viewing the first div. Is there a way to hide the overflow when the divs that cause the overflow are out of view?

Comment: set height and overflow scroll  only on second content div

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9WsnA/5/)

```
document.getElementById("anc").addEventListener("click", function() {
   var serpcontainer = document.getElementById("serpcontainer");
   if (serpcontainer.className.indexOf("serp") > -1) {
       serpcontainer.className = "";
   }
   else {
       serpcontainer.className = "serp";
   }
}, false);
```

Update it as needed...

Comment: Works great! But the code below is more specific to my needs. Thanks for the help!